# GPO still applying old setting

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

**AD functional level:** 2003

**4 DCs:** One Server '03 R2 (SP2), three Server '08 R2s.

**GPO:** ADM for Microsoft Communicator created a few years ago.

**Usage:** The ADM does a few things, but one of which is setting Lync (we upgraded) to force connect to our old OCS server.

**Problem:** I changed the GPO to force connect to the new server (all I did was update the setting in the ADM).
The GPO reflects the changes in the report, but it is still pushing out the setting to connect to the old OCS server (even to brand new computers). This has been happening for a few days now, I'm not sure what the problem is.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a link to the [ADM](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1d6SZ1SfXVOWFJVQm9lZlB3Sk0/edit?usp=sharing) (I've stripped away all the settings we don't use for an easier read).

I played around in a test OU with a custom ADM, and I noticed that after changing a setting, it simply added the new value to the report without removing the previous value. In other words the one setting was now applying a "1", then a "0" in the same field, negating its self. This was shown in the report however, and the current ADM's report doesn't show any negating duplicates, but I'm still skeptical.

Comment: It may help if you could link to the ADM. But essentially, if your configuring things that are outside of one of the `Policies` keys in the registry, then it's tattooing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we do indeed have a replication issue between the 2003 server and the 2008r2 servers. As a quick fix, I recreated the GPO and manually replicated the sysvol folder. Hopefully we won't need to edit any ADM based GPOs...

I do know that there is a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978055) with mixed DCs, but the boss-man has halted any further major projects. >:(